# Why do I need to put in what the var is here and why does it give me a number as an answer? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Here is my code and I am trying to practice making a for and a while loop with the while loop making use of a random number.

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  console.log("This is a for loop");
}

var random= Math.random();
while(random<0.5){
  console.log("This is a while loop");
  random =Math.random();
}
```

It seems to not display the number however when I change the penultimate line to be:

```
var random =Math.random();
```

Sorry I'm quite new to coding so if this question is stupid I apologise in advance

Comment: There is no code in your posting that would output a number. Can you post both examples?

Comment: You'd have to output the number if you wanted to see it like console.log(random);

Comment: There is an extremely good chance that your initial `var random` will be a float larger than 0.5, in which case the while loop will not run.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I'd say about a 50% chance

Comment: @PaulS. you might be on to something there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 50% chance that the `while` condition will be `false` on the first attempt. In such cases you will never see the loop's body being run.

```
var random = Math.random();
console.log('Initial value of random is', random);
if (random >= 0.5) console.warn('the while loop will not run');
while(random < 0.5) {
    console.log("This is a while loop");
    random = Math.random();
}
```

---

In your case, you may have wanted to write a [`do..while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop

```
var random;
do { // go into this block
    console.log("This is a while loop");
    random = Math.random();
} while (random < 0.5); // if condition true, go back to the `do`
```

---

If you're just starting with loops, it may be useful to consider how to re-write `for` loops as `while` loops

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    console.log("This is a while loop");
    i++;
}
```

This isn't so you use `while` instead of `for` when a `for` is more natural, but so you get a feel for `while` loops, how they work and how sometimes they will suit the code you're trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  console.log("this is a for loop. the variable is:" + i);
}

var random= Math.random();
while(random<0.5){
  console.log("This is a while loop the variable is:" + random);
  random =Math.random();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome Joe.   Mark this as answered if you're satisfied.